# React Navigation + Higher Order Component (HOC) For Checking Authentication/Protected Routes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, higher-order-components

I'm having an issue where I'm using a Higher Order Component to checked if a user is authenticated (checkAuth). My issue is that the route seems to be protected since it doesn't the screen, but it does load the bottom tab navigation, header, and doesn't route back to the Login screen.

[HERE'S WHAT THE ISSUE LOOKS LIKE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DMGJT.jpg)

**The checkAuthTest is just a function I wrote to navigate to the Conversations screen:**

```
  // Check Auth Test (Testing)
  checkAuthTest = () => {
    try {
      console.log('Navigating to App Stack')
      console.log(`Current User: ${firebase.auth().currentUser}`);

      // this.props.navigation.navigate('AppStack');
      // this.props.navigation.navigate('AuthLoading');
      this.props.navigation.navigate('Conversations');
    }
    catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
```

**Higher Order Component:**

If the user is authenticated, the Higher Order Component routes the user to the component. If the user is not authenticated, the Higher Order Component routes the user back to the login screen.

```
// Imports: Dependencies
import React from 'react';
import firebase from 'firebase';

// Imports: Screens
import Login from '../../screens/auth-stack/Login';

// Higher Order Component: Check Auth
const CheckAuth = (OriginalComponent) => props => {
  class CheckAuth extends React.Component {    
    render() {
      // Check Authentication (Working)
      if (firebase.auth().currentUser !== null) {
        return <OriginalComponent {...this.props} />
      }
      // Redirect To Login (Not Working)
      else {
        return <Login />
      }
    }
  }

  // Return Check Auth Component
  return CheckAuth;
}

// Exports
export default CheckAuth;
```

**React Navigation:**
I'm using React Navigation and here's my setup:

```
// React Navigation: Auth Stack Navigator
export const AuthStack = createStackNavigator({
  Login: Login,
  AuthLoading: AuthLoading,
});

// React Navigation: Messaging Stack Navigator
export const MessagingStack = createStackNavigator({
  Conversations: Conversations,
  Message: Message,
  NewMessage: NewMessage,
});

// React Navigation: Profile Stack Navigator
export const ProfileStack = createStackNavigator({
  Profile: Profile,
},
{
  mode: 'modal',
});

// React Navigation: App Stack Navigator
export const AppStack = createBottomTabNavigator({
  Message: {
    screen: MessagingStack,
    navigationOptions: {
      tabBarLabel: 'Message',
      tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
        <Icon name="ios-chatboxes" color={tintColor} size={26} />
      ),
    }
  },
  Profile: {
    screen: ProfileStack,
    navigationOptions: {
      tabBarLabel: 'Profile',
      tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
        <Icon name="ios-contact" color={tintColor} size={28} />
      ),
    }
  }
});

// React Navigation: Switch Container
export const AppContainer = createAppContainer(createSwitchNavigator(
  {
    AuthStack: AuthStack,
    AppStack: AppStack,
  },
    // Options
  {
    initialRouteName: 'AuthStack',
    // initialRouteName: 'AppStack',
  }
));
```

**Conversations Screen Export:**

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(checkAuth(Conversations));
```

**Login Component**

```
// Imports: Dependencies
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Button, SafeAreaView, StyleSheet, Text } from 'react-native';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

// Imports: Redux Actions
import { 
  loginWithAppleRequest,
} from '../../redux/actions/authActions';

// TEST: Delete Later
import firebase from 'firebase';
import { appleAuth } from '../../firebase/firebase';

// Imports: Components
import FBLoginButton from '../../components/FacebookLoginButton';
import GoogleLoginButton from '../../components/GoogleLoginButton';
import SignOutButton from '../../components/SignOutButton';

// Screen: Login
class Login extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  // React Navigation: Options
  static navigationOptions = {
    headerStyle: {
      elevation: 0,
      shadowOpacity: 0,
      borderBottomWidth: 0,
    }
  };

  // Login With Apple
  loginWithApple = () => {
    try {
      firebase
      .auth()
      .signInWithPopup(appleAuth)
      .then((result) => {
        // The signed-in user info.
        let user = result.user;
        // You can also get the Apple OAuth Access and ID Tokens.
        let accessToken = result.credential.accessToken;
        let idToken = result.credential.idToken;

        console.log('User');
        console.log(user);

        console.log('Access Token');
        console.log(accessToken);

        console.log('ID Token');
        console.log(idToken);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        // Handle Errors here.
        let errorCode = error.code;
        let errorMessage = error.message;
        // The email of the user's account used.
        let email = error.email;
        // The firebase.auth.AuthCredential type that was used.
        let credential = error.credential;

        console.log('Error Code');
        console.log(errorCode);

        console.log('Error Message');
        console.log(errorMessage);

        console.log('Email');
        console.log(email);

        console.log('Credential');
        console.log(credential);
      });
    }
    catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  // Check Auth Test (Testing)
  checkAuthTest = () => {
    try {
      console.log('Navigating to App Stack')
      console.log(`Current User: ${firebase.auth().currentUser}`);

      // this.props.navigation.navigate('AppStack');
      // this.props.navigation.navigate('AuthLoading');
      this.props.navigation.navigate('Conversations');
    }
    catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>        
        <GoogleLoginButton />
        <FBLoginButton />

        <Button onPress={this.checkAuthTest} title="Check Auth Test" />

        <SignOutButton />

      </SafeAreaView>
    )
  }
}

// Styles
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    height: '100%',
    display: 'flex',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
});

// Map State To Props (Redux Store --> Component)
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  // Redux Store --> Component
  return {
    // uid: state.authReducer.uid,
  };
};

// Map Dispatch To Props (Dispatch Actions To Redux Store To Grab Data)
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  // Action
  return {
    // Redux: Dispatch Login With Apple Action
    reduxLoginWithAppleRequest: () => dispatch(loginWithAppleRequest()),
  };
};

// Exports
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Login);
```

Comment: I think it has to do with how to export your login component, could you add this code so I could review it?

Comment: Just added it the code for the Login screen. Thanks for looking!

Answer (score 1):

The error tells you what's wrong. You're returning a function instead of an element:

```js
const CheckAuth = (OriginalComponent) => props => {
  class CheckAuth extends React.Component {
    // ...
  }

  // Return Check Auth Component
  return CheckAuth;
}
```

Now when you use it:

```js
CheckAuth(Conversations)
```

Results in:

```js
const Component = props => {
  class CheckAuth extends React.Component {
    // ...
  }

  // This is a component but you're returning a function instead an element
  return CheckAuth;
}
```

You probably want:

```js
const CheckAuth = (OriginalComponent) => {
  class CheckAuthComponent extends React.Component {
    // ...
  }

  // Return Check Auth Component
  return CheckAuthComponent;
}
```

Here I have removed the extra `props =>`, since you need to return a component here (`CheckAuth`), not a function returning a component (`props => CheckAuth`).

Comment: So it's working now and navigating to the login screen, but the header and tab navigator from React Navigation are still present. And idea what that could be? When the button is pressed, it should navigate to the Conversations screen (App Stack), but the HOC returns the Login screen (Auth Stack).